# Drawing this picture using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I need to draw the follwing picture, is there anyone who can help me with that? I've never used TikZ so I don't really know how to draw this!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? What do you mean by `tax`? While somebody may  be prepared to do your work for you, you stand a better chance of getting a good range of answers if you provide the code you have got so far in the form of a minimal document people can compile. Copying content from images is boring. Setting problems up is boring. Solving them is a different matter. If you really don't want to do anything for yourself, I recommend desiring a cute or especially challenging picture rather than this one. If you involve ducks, you'll stand a better chance.

Comment: »Original secret |⟩ → Replicated secret |⟩« violates the [no-cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem).

Answer (score 5):

I am also new to TikZ.  This is the third time, I've worked with it.  I managed by reading the manual while trying to solve your question.  It was fun, especially, as I managed to master it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% Define a style for the boxes.
\tikzset{boxes/.style={ultra thick, rounded corners=5pt,black}}
\tikzset{aline/.style={>=stealth},
         aline/.default=black}
\tikzset{sbox/.style={thick,rounded corners=2pt,draw=white,fill=white}}
\tikzset{oval/.style={fill=white,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.05]
  % Draw the long red (starting) line
  \draw[aline,red, ->] (25,195) -- (25,150);
  % and insert the labeling text
  \draw(25,195) node[left]{\parbox{2cm}{\raggedleft
      Original\\secret}} node[right] {$\Psi$};
  % the text above the top arrows
  \draw(50,175) node[above] {ancillary states};
  % Draw the next, normal black lines, each 10 mm apart from each
  % other
  \foreach \x in {10, 20, ..., 50}
     \draw[aline,->] (25+\x,175) -- (25+\x,150);
  % draw the Box with the label AI   
  \draw[boxes] (20,130) rectangle +(60,20);
  \draw(50,140) node {\textbf{AI}};
  % draw a circle around the box
  \draw[blue] (50,140) ellipse [x radius=50, y radius=20];
  \draw (90,155)  node[right] {\textcolor{blue}{dealer}};
  % Draw the first two lines, that end in "n Shares" box
  \foreach \x in {0,10}
     \draw [aline] (25+\x,130) -- (25+\x,100);
  % Draw the next bunch of lines, that end in the lower AI box.
  \foreach \x in {20, 30, ..., 50}
     \draw[aline,->] (25+\x,130) -- (25+\x,60);
  % Draw the lower AI box.  You can also calculate the coordinates
  \draw[boxes] (35,40) rectangle +(50,20);
  \draw(35+25,40+10) node{\textbf{AI}};
  % draw another ellipse around the box
  \draw[blue] (60,50) ellipse [x radius=45, y radius=18];
  \draw (100,60)  node[right] {\parbox{3cm}{\color{blue} $k$
      collaborating\\\hspace*{3mm}players}};
 % Draw the last lines.  One long and three shorter ones
  \foreach \x in {10, 20, 30}
      \draw[aline,->] (45+\x,40) -- (45+\x,25);
  \draw[aline,red,->] (45,40) -- (45,5);
  % and mount the label to it
  \draw(45,5) node[left] {\parbox{2cm}{\raggedleft
      replicated\\secret}} node [right]{$\Psi$};
  % Lay another box over the image, clipping  the vertical lines of
  \draw[sbox] (20,100) rectangle (80,110);
  \draw(50,105) node {$n$ Shares};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Of course, you are welcome, to adapt the styles etc. to your needs.

Comment: `aline/.default=black` doesn't do anything, does it? Try changing it to red.

Comment: I copied it from the TikZ manual.  There is also an example, where you define aline features and set a default color, which can be changed afterwards. You are right, one could add some linewidth to the style definition besides the arrows.